# Perfect secrecy is maintained for other plaintext prob distributions?

Tags: perfect-secrecy

> Suppose a cryptosystem achieves perfect secrecy for a particular plaintext probability distribution. Prove that perfect secrecy is maintained for any other plaintext probability distribution.

Having trouble starting this one. Just a hint to get started would be appreciated.

I am aware that a cryptosystem is said to be perfectly secure if $P(X|Y)=P(X)$ for all $x\in\mathcal{P}, y\in\mathcal{C}$

Comment: related: [How is the One Time Pad (OTP) perfectly secure?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31084/23623)